# Typescript indexing a partial type, react-hook-form dirty fields to updated fields

Tags: typescript

In `react-hook-form` you get `dirtyFields` which are the updated fields = true

```
v = {
    username: 'alice',
    email: 'alice@example.com',
    role: 'USER'
}

dirtyFields = {
    username: true
}
```

I want to only send the updated fields (username in this case)

I tried this

```
type User = {
    username: string
    email: string
    role: 'ADMIN' | 'USER'
}

function submitForm (v: User, dirtyFields: Partial<Record<keyof User, boolean>>) {
    const updated: Partial<User> = {}

    Object.keys(dirtyFields).forEach(field => {
        updated[field] = v[field as keyof User]
    })

    return updated
}
```

But I'm getting this error in `updated[field]`

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Partial<User>'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Partial<User>'.(7053)
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Na4vpw) meet your needs?  If so I will write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?  (This is an aside: is every property value in `dirtyFields` equal to `true`?  Or is it sometimes `false`?  If it's always `true` then you should write `Partial<Record<keyof User, true>>`.  If it's sometimes `false` then you should probably check `dirtyFields[field]` before doing the update.  Either way you should probably fix that part of the question so it's not distracting)

Comment: I think it will 1) always be true, and 2) only the updated fields. I've found a working solution, but your solution looks good too. If you were to post it as an answer I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is that `field` is seen as type `string`, and `User` doesn't have a string [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures).  This is a consequence of the fact that  `Object.keys(obj)` returns `string[]` instead of `Array<keyof typeof obj>`, for reasons laid out in the answer to [Why doesn't Object.keys return a keyof type in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55012174/2887218).

So if you want the compiler to treat each element at `keyof User`, you'll need to [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) the type somewhere.  My choice is usually to write `(Object.keys(dirtyFields) as Array<keyof User>)`.

But you'd still have an error:

```
(Object.keys(dirtyFields) as Array<keyof User>).
    forEach(field => {
        updated[field] = v[field]; // error!
        //^^^^^^^^^^^^
        // Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"ADMIN" | "USER" | undefined'.
    });
```

because the compiler doesn't follow the logic that `field` is identical on both sides of the assignment.  It is looking at the types and not variable identities, so it treats that assignment like `updated[field1] = v[field2]` where `field1` and `field2` are both of type `keyof User`.  It makes sense that this should be an error, but precisely because `field1` and `field2` might be different.  This error was implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#30769](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769) but has caused a bunch of grief for TS programmers.  The workaround/fix for this is laid out [in a comment on the same issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769#issuecomment-498428559): use [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html):

```
(Object.keys(dirtyFields) as Array<keyof User>).
    forEach(<K extends keyof User>(field: K) => {
        updated[field] = v[field];  // okay
    })
```

Now the callback to `forEach()` is generic in `K`, the type of `field`, which is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `keyof User`.  And the compiler sees the right side of the assignment as `User[K]` while the left is `Partial<User>[K]`, and the assignment succeeds.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATlAvFA3gKCjqBXBRAOwEMBbCALijmEQEsiBzbXCMk+gG2toedY5EAey5UoAcgCCAEQCyASQByEqAB9JMAMoBRAEoTMAX0yYAZniIBjYPWFEaeAEZl6wAGLDEZABQA3angkABooABN6RFB3egguMLhqAAUSKPoSLgAePQgrLzDMgGsIEGEzWEJQujwIAD5agEoMQSg8olp8MDCSYAgw5NTbDMygxFrUDCMAblNcKB8AeScAK1zgADpikDgfCKiQGLiEppI4KClERBIQIpKyiqRG9Za5sy8dEisACx8zWPjUOMsHMQbg8F0en0ANp-I4AXQmfhh-zCcKmUAA9BioEgRIgAIQvUGYjEAPXJFMp5KJoKxUAAKuBoBI+IwmKp6GciMJgFBTnB6ExSE4xFBgMIxUzJAAiWSKJTS9RQaXafSKjSWMIQP5EPoSZ7EqBGBozFqLFZrTYlHZ7aIouAnM4XK43Lb3UZPGlQN6ID7fHyZADSOIAHr0iAkoG7yh7fijqIGmiggV65uDur0wsj4Yjs-E0V7jaa5ogIMA8MROhm+sYgA)

Answer (score 0):

User `word#1438` on Discord gave me a solution

```
type User = {
    username: string
    email: string
    role: 'ADMIN' | 'USER'
}

function sendValues(u: User, dirtyValues: Partial<Record<keyof User, boolean>>) {
    const updated: Partial<Record<keyof User, string>> = {}

    function isTypeOfUser(key: string): key is keyof User {
        return key in u
    }

    Object.keys(dirtyValues).forEach(f => {
        if(!isTypeOfUser(f)) return
        updated[f] = u[f as keyof User]
    })

    return updated
}
```