# Pass associated value in Typescript object for certain enum keys

Tags: reactjs, typescript, enums

I am trying to iterate through an object where the keys are each case from an enum and the value is `any` type (using Typescript). This works fine when the value in the object is a predefined constant, but one of the values needs to use a provided string to generate a return object. Is there a way I can do this in Typescript? I will show a stripped down sample of what I am doing below.

**Object Constants**

```
export const injected = new InjectedConnector({
  supportedChainIds: [1, 3, 4, 5, 42],
});

export const walletconnect = new WalletConnectConnector({
  rpc: RPC_URLS,
  chainId: 1,
  bridge: 'https://bridge.walletconnect.org',
  qrcode: true,
});

export const walletlink = new WalletLinkConnector({
  url: RPC_URLS[1],
  appName: 'web3-react example',
  supportedChainIds: [1, 3, 4, 5, 42, 10, 137, 69, 420, 80001],
});

export const magic = (email: string) => {
  return new MagicConnector({
    apiKey: 'apiKey',
    chainId: 1,
    email: email,
  });
};
```

**Enum and object to iterate over in front end**

```
enum ConnectorNames {
  Injected = 'MetaMask',
  WalletConnect = 'WalletConnect',
  WalletLink = 'Coinbase Wallet',
  Magic = 'Email',
}

const connectorsByName: { [connectorName in ConnectorNames]: any } = {
  [ConnectorNames.Injected]: injected,
  [ConnectorNames.WalletConnect]: walletconnect,
  [ConnectorNames.WalletLink]: walletlink,
  // Would like to give magic an associated string value to pass into magic const above,
  // somehting like `magic(test@gmail.com)`
  [ConnectorNames.Magic]: magic,
};
```

**Front End TSX**

```
const TestComponent = () => {
  const [connector, setConnector] = useState<any>(null);
  const testString = 'Hello, World!';
  return (
    <>
      {Object.keys(connectorsByName).map((name) => {
        // Would like to pass in test string to the connector/name in some way, and have magic
        // consume it and the other 3 enum cases that dont need the associated value ignore it
        const currentConnector =
          connectorsByName[name as keyof typeof connectorsByName];
        return (
          <div
            className=" bg-white rounded-lg p-4 hover:cursor-pointer min-w-[25vw]"
            key={name}
            onClick={() => {
              setConnector(currentConnector);
            }}
          ></div>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
};

export default TestComponent;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use type assertion for the return value of `Object.keys()` API. See [Why doesn't Object.keys return a keyof type in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55012174/why-doesnt-object-keys-return-a-keyof-type-in-typescript)

```
enum ConnectorNames {
    Injected = 'MetaMask',
    WalletConnect = 'WalletConnect',
    WalletLink = 'Coinbase Wallet',
    Magic = 'Email',
}

const connectorsByName: Record<ConnectorNames, any> = {
    [ConnectorNames.Injected]: () => 1,
    [ConnectorNames.WalletConnect]: () => '2',
    [ConnectorNames.WalletLink]: () => true,
    [ConnectorNames.Magic]: () => null,
};

(Object.keys(connectorsByName) as ConnectorNames[]).map((name) => {
    const currentConnector = connectorsByName[name];
})
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=2&ssc=27&pln=3&pc=37#code/KYOwrgtgBAwg9iEwDGAXOAnAcgQwsAZygG8AoKCqASRACsVVgATKAXigHIBZYVHLnAQDWHADTlKAdRwAbGb3iIGbTtLkKESNGIkU181ABkAliCEqO8UwCNBwKPt47KUAQHNjyCwFEIOYzI6AL6kpMgIBKhQ4UpomAQAQgCeuPgAXFAASiiYTAA8ilro2HiEolA4IEkAfCpkLgDahQyYqYQAdDT0aMwAuhkAFACUbLUAjOKNzXEl+ATtjqjTqP1Qw6OcAEzOlE2aLbMdiyZmq+ustagYYMCTu8utpfPunmcjF1DgcuJBANyhAwA8tZuqh2kJgEkCAMYkV4sk2iNBLB9jM2gQGr0hu0-AAHAYDECld61eqUGKRaJgDAYUBLVHFFSwg6JFKlBpE-C9f5BIZAA)