# how to correcly type the key of a Record in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have the following function that filter the props of an object according to a filtering function:

```js
function filterProps<K extends string, V>(object: Record<K, V>, fn: (key:K, value: V, object: Record<K, V>) => unknown) {
  // return a new object with only the properties filtered by fn
  return Object.entries(object).reduce( 
    (acum, [key, value]) => fn(key, value, object) ? {...acum, [key]: value } : acum, 
    {} as Record<K, V>
  )
}
```

I'm getting the error:

```
(parameter) key: string
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'K'.
  'string' is assignable to the constraint of type 'K', but 'K' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'string | number | symbol'.(2345)
```

how should I type '`key` to avoid that error?

Note: playground available [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMGAbKBTATgBS3ABwGcAeAaUQwA9MwATIxIqLGMAcwBpEA1APgAUcAEYArDNABciAEoS4WOuW79uwMNIEBrDAE9JZbgDcAhqhAZpPbiPFTZ8xct58AlIgC8fROC1g4AO5g7gDeAFCIiAD0UYhYGFAgWEgmiGAYAYi2ElCIATBQABZZYKi6iEUYiAT4BNiwGIwo6NgYdIjC5eoRcQlJSADyYjkAdBhgLDCNQsPQriPxdCAQGAKIPZECJhAgALbcANo6usZmFgC67l7IYNp6p+YYNrNQ7gD8iCEj39t7h8fnaSmR6IAC+iGkv3260ikRC4JMjDkEAUSkMLh6rjC4PWYRRYGYWQAjJ5Pj0wCZdpZEAByIiImmcHomdjUokABiZkSI-Up1PAdAwKHSdC5lF2JjQ0jpiIAAuwJWgRijdjTsQBuMJ4hCE+JEAg6qoeMmRADCcF2BvSE2lKqt4ygjJ6NUIRGkYBAqFQYt2CmpdMSwGATsi1Ag5hW0qpatBmu1BLgqAwI1QcHYa2amFwtSIQiJ3G0xiu3i0ng8xppFOjrix+KIieTqfTyDQWbwrrzBa0Rc83iMNa1dYbKbTGdb2HbxE7iELiH7vbniAAZEvEAdK3zGbSMIrUDTziM2OGQILc1oa1j4-WkyPm5mJzmBHqrUQnjOXQQHhZi3OzlUV++tRlhW5qWggDo0ogAA+UHVEB5YVh+RA0gOQA)

Comment: For your first question, the keys returned by `Object.entries` are all strings. This is because a number used as a key is coerced to a string (that's how JavaScript works), and because `Object.entries` does not return properties with symbol keys.

Comment: The issue is that `Object.entries()` isn't strongly typed enough for your purposes; it is technically unsound to have it return `Array<[K, V]>` (because object types are not sealed, similar to `Object.keys()` returning `string[]` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55012174/2887218)).  You can work around it with a type assertion like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wXz99m).  Does that fully address your question?  If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: From [the MDN docs for `Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries): "`Object.entries()` returns an array whose elements are arrays corresponding to the **enumerable string-keyed** property key-value pairs found directly upon `object`." (emphasis mine)

Comment: @jcalz: it seems like an explicit type assertion is the correct answer, please DO write it up so I can accept it, thanks a lot!

Comment: you can cast key to `K` like this: `fn(key as K, value, object)`

Comment: Addition to my earlier comment: numeric keys are not simply coerced to strings. It is more detailed than that. But you can (for the most part) treat it like that.

Answer (score 1):

The TypeScript [typings](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/41e4139357d39ae589b22bd1c8dacf03c92e1fae/lib/lib.es2017.object.d.ts#L34-L44) for [the `Object.entries()` static method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) are

```
interface ObjectConstructor {
    entries<T>(o: { [s: string]: T } | ArrayLike<T>): [string, T][];
    entries(o: {}): [string, any][];
}
```

which both return an array of key-value tuples where the key is of type `string`.  The reason why you don't get `K` is because object types in TypeScript are not "sealed" or "exact" (as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#12936](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936)); it is always possible for an object to have more properties than TypeScript knows about.  See [Why doesn't Object.keys return a keyof type in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55012174/why-doesnt-object-keys-return-a-keyof-type-in-typescript) for a similar question/answer about `Object.keys()` returning `string[]`.

---

For example, the following situation can occur:

```
interface Foo {
  bar: string,
  baz: string;
}
const x = { bar: "abc", baz: "def", qux: 123 };
const y: Foo = x; // okay
```

Notice how the assignment `const y: Foo = x` succeeds; that's because `x` contains all the properties required in `Foo` and *excess properties do not invalidate the assignment*.  There are [excess property checks on *object literals*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks) like `const y: Foo = { bar: "abc", baz: "def", qux: 123 }`, but that fails because information about `qux` will be completely forgotten by the compiler (and is therefore considered a mistake) and not because `qux` violates anything.

And *that* means your `filterProps()` method implementation is technically unsafe, since I could write

```
filterProps(y, (k, v) => v.toUpperCase() === v) // compiles, but
//  RUNTIME ERROR! v.toUpperCase is not a function
```

which erroneously assumes that `v` will be of type `string`.  The call compiles without error because `filterProps()`'s call signature allows it, but then the implementation ends up treating a `number` as a `string` and you get a runtime error.

So that's why the error is there.  What you're doing is technically unsafe.

---

If you are confident that your object won't actually have such excess properties of an unexpected type, then you can [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that to the compiler.  One way to do that is to assert that  `Object.entries(object)` returns `Array<[K, V]>`, as follows:

```
function filterProps<K extends string | symbol | number, V>(
  object: Record<K, V>, fn: (key: K, value: V, object: Record<K, V>) => unknown) {
 
  return (Object.entries(object) as Array<[K, V]>).reduce(
  // --------------------------> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    (acum, [key, value]) => fn(key, value, object) ? { ...acum, [key]: value } : acum,
    {} as Record<K, V>
  )
}
```

Now the implementation compiles without error, because the compiler assumes you know what you're doing and that `Object.entries(object)` will return an `Array<[K, V]>` as you've claimed.

This doesn't make the function any safer, since you can still call `filterProps(y, (k, v) => v.toUpperCase() === v)` , but the type assertion shifts responsibility for preventing such things from the compiler to you.  So proceed at your own risk!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMGAbKBTATgBS3ABwGcAeAaUQwA9MwATIxIqLGMAc0QB8mBPAWwBGcVN0RgQQ7ABpEANQB8ACgBQiRHEEArDNABciAEq64WOuVmLZwMAaUBrDLwNlZANwCGqEBgNzZmjr6RiZmFvIKAJSIALwKiOD2YHAA7mDRAN5qaohYGFAgWEhKAPLaulAAdBhgLDAYREqBFdEejACCWFgevCQA2q7yALpRlXl0IBAYqurqSh4QkrJ9jrzuXj5D0XHIYA5O694YAeXQ0QD8iBmIlbcLS4grTkMGnkeIAL6IBvf80jnqDJfNohCCmcyDRQ5SIqD4qFRgsDMDQARliVxyYA8-F8iAA5EQ2nj-uoPOxcSiAAwkpiFLE4gzgOgYFBgDB0GkYfgeNAGAltAAC7G5aEqYP4eNhAG54YjkXkiAQEEQMOisuoAMJwfhKtm1Pni3U1KDEnIEfDEAwSVCoGn8Uy4gkFYDAU3qagQbxTPk4yUfGUI5UiDCVVBwdhKFDobB4QiNOAo2QOdzbeL2WIxGL4+kYPGRGFy4Oh8ORtCYXAW+OJxDJxBuVN1-OyoOoENhiNR8ux4hNau1+uxeJuRAAMhHjzxOeJ+K5PNQeKGlTYnpAzMa9nzMMDSKL7dL0YrcaUCt1KqT5sIhx8DbePlH46UF4IGazeK1OoQxrx3B4T5f+KfIg83zAM2HLYAFlVAAxOA4AxdRBA8LADGYVgOBpRCAC8ULqDgZThOUoEQKg1UQRDkMQAAiDxBAgSjZCwgxKOZYB6MQABHEAqAMFEACYAGZPhlQjEGcRAYLgrMqClRAAHpZI0ewehUTsY0rJQ1hrewU0HOtKigOAAFUCAIbANTaaZtkzRs5IUw00AaBiQCgFR5MQQBeDcAUp2jEMgA5AAVABJABZABRRBQsMQwSkMABCPSDOM0ysHMlVEBgRhkiIjxkHAaB4DAIA)

Comment: great answer and excellent all the explanations, wish you lots of upvotes!