# Access `in keyof T` using a string

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm having issues accessing a property in a object using a string index, where the interface is defined using `in keyof`.

Take this code:

```
interface IFilm {
    name: string;
    author: string;
}
type IExtra<T extends  {}> = {
    [index in keyof T]: number;
};

const film : IFilm = { name: "FilmName", author: "AuthorName"};
const extra : IExtra<IFilm> = {  name: 1, author: 2};

Object.keys(film).forEach(X => {
    extra[x] = 3; // Error here!!
});
```

Where I try to access `extra[x]` I got this error:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type 'IExtra'.

I'm getting why: typescript cannot know that `x` contains only string that are actually valid for the constraint `in keyof T`.
Thus, how can I rewrite this, or make TypeScript aware that this is valid code? I know I can using `(extra as any)[x]`,  but I'd like to be "type-checked" :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't Object.keys return a keyof type in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55012174/why-doesnt-object-keys-return-a-keyof-type-in-typescript)  Eventhough the linked question is *"Why"*, some of the answers provide workarounds for the *"How"*

Comment: Your `x` and `X` have different case so they are different variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Object.keys` doesn't return `keyof T`, because TS does not guarantes that there are no other keys:

```
const notAFilm = { name: '123', author: 'asd', blah: true }
const badFilm: IFilm = notAFilm
const badKeys = Object.keys(badFilm)
console.log(badKeys) // ["name", "author", "blah"]
```

If you are sure there is no other keys, make an alternative which knows that:

```
interface IFilm {
    name: string;
    author: string;
}
type IExtra<T extends {}> = {
    [index in keyof T]: number;
};

const film: IFilm = { name: "FilmName", author: "AuthorName" };
const extra: IExtra<IFilm> = { name: 1, author: 2 };

/** works as expected only if there is no unknown keys */
function recordKeys<T extends {}>(o: T): (keyof T)[] {
    return Object.keys(o) as (keyof T)[]
}

recordKeys(film).forEach(x => {
    extra[x] = 3; // works fine
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You issue is that `Object.keys<T>` returns a `string`, not a `key of T`.

You need yo do a type assertion   `extra[x as keyof IFilm] = 3;`

If you want to iterate over typed keys, use a `Map`.