# Get the keys of a generic type object

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, generics

I need to get the names of the keys of the object that comes as generic type `T`

I tried to do this through an

```
function getGnericTypeKeys<T>(): string[] {
  return Object.keys({} as T);
}
```

and

```
function getGnericTypeKeys<T>(): string[] {
  return Object.getOwnProperties({} as T);
}
```

and

```
function getGnericTypeKeys<T>(): string[] {
  return Reflect.ownKeys({} as T);
}
```

Comment: Let me ask you, are you familiar with the concept of _type-erasure_?

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55012174/why-doesnt-object-keys-return-a-keyof-type-in-typescript

Comment: You say "keys of the object" but the only object you're using is `{}`, which has no keys.  Where is the object whose keys you want to get?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this can help you.

```
function getGnericTypeKeys<T extends {}>(obj: T): (keyof T)[] {
  return Object.keys(obj) as (keyof T)[];
}
```

Comment: [Behemoth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77132284/get-the-keys-of-a-generic-type-object/77132346#comment135976148_77132284) gave a more meaningful discussion.